# Google charts слишком широкие на экране телефона

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chart

[На своем Wordpress-сайте](https://slova.de/player-5/) я показываю 2 диаграммы при помощи Google Charts и, к сожалению, на экране мобильных устройств они шире, чем ширина экрана:

[image: скриншот iPhone 7]

Вот мой актуальный HTML-код:

```
<H2 ALIGN="center">Статистика результатов</H2>
<DIV ID="pieChart" CLASS="gchart"><IMG SRC="/words/images/loader.gif" WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="60"></DIV>

<H2 ALIGN="center">Статистика слов</H2>
<DIV ID="barChart" CLASS="gchart"><IMG SRC="/words/images/loader.gif" WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="60"></DIV>
```

Вот мой актуальный [CSS-код](https://slova.de/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/style.css):

```
div.gchart {
        width: 590px;
        height: 360px;
        margin: auto;
}
```

Видимо в моем CSS-коде и причина, так как я просто устанавливаю ширину обоих графиков в 590 пикселей.

Как решают такие проблемы? Хотелось бы, чтобы на экранов телефонов ширина графиков была бы 100% вместо 590 пикселей.

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:

Вот еще мой JavaScript-код, как его подправить? Видимо `width: 590` надо убирать?

```
function drawResults() {
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/words/results.php',
                data: { uid: <?= $uid ?> },
                dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(jsonData) {
                var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                var options = {
                        width: 590,
                        height: 360,
                        pieHole: 0.2,
                        pieSliceText: 'none',
                        tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
                        legend: { position: 'left', alignment: 'center', maxLines: 2 }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));
                chart.draw(dt, options);
        });
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите что такое Media Queries в CSS, вопрос решается одной строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width : 544px) {
    div.gchart {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 360px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я бы сам не догадался про `min-height: 360px`. А почему `544px`? Это среднестатистическая ширина телефонных экранов?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber да, раньше писали 320, сейчас 544. Это можно подглядывать у Bootstrap, например

Comment: Странно, но почему-то не помогает - [та же картина](https://slova.de/player-9794/) в моем iPhone 7. Может быть как-то мешает стиль Wordpress?

Comment: Там во всех внутренних тегах прописаны размеры http://screenshot.kobzarev.com/2019-07-01-1561973959.png их тоже надо перебивать!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (+1), но те внутренние таги я не создаю, это наверное Google Charts. Мой HTML-код целиком указан в моем вопросе, и там я не указываю размеры. А в JavaScript-кодe указываю (добавил в вопрос).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber для второго вопроса - создайте отдельную ветку.